# Migration 2_deploy_contracts invalid or does not take any parameters at Object.run()

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

I am trying to compile my smart contracts using `truffle pet-shop`. I have the following contract in directory **election/contracts/election.sol** ;

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.6.0;
contract Election{
    string public candidate;
    constructor() public{
        candidate="Zeeshan";
    }
}
```

The migration file to deploy contracts in directory **election/migrations/2_deploy_contracts1.js** is as follows;

```
var Election1=artifacts.require("election.sol");
module.export=function(deployer){
    deployer.deploy(Election1)
};
```

I am using the following command to migrate the contracts:

> truffle migrate

And I am getting the following results:

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\Election.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\election.sol
> Artifacts written to D:\Notes\BCS\Semester 8\FYP\Practise Coding\dapp university 2 hr video code\election\build\contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.5.8+commit.23d335f2.Emscripten.clang


Starting migrations...
======================
> Network name:    'development'
> Network id:      5777
> Block gas limit: 0x6691b7


2_deploy_contracts1.js
======================
Error: Error: Migration D:\Notes\BCS\Semester 8\FYP\Practise Coding\dapp university 2 hr video code\election\migrations\2_deploy_contracts1.js invalid or does not take any parameters
    at Object.run (C:\Users\mk141\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-migrate\index.js:92:1)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
Truffle v5.0.30 (core: 5.0.30)
Node v10.16.1
```

Its also compiling `Election.sol` because I renamed `election.sol` to `Election.sol` and it stores `election.sol` in cache perhaps.

As you can see above its giving **Error:Migration 2_deploy_contracts invalid or does not take any parameters at Object.run()** and i don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: Remove build/ directory and try again.

Comment: It's giving the same error. First time when i migrated it gives no error. But now it's giving that error. Even i created a new pet-shop box and created the new contract and migration file in it

Comment: But your comment is helpful in many other things

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was making a mistake in `2_deploy_contracts1.js` file. There was typo instead of `module.export` I need to write `module.exports`. So the new 2_deploy_contracts1.js file will be;

```
var Election1=artifacts.require("election.sol");
module.exports=function(deployer){
    deployer.deploy(Election1)
};
```

Also, I was using the following command to migrate again;

> truffle migrate

Instead, I should use the following command if I am migrating again;

> truffle migrate --reset

We use this command because we already migrated our smart contracts in the `build folder`. This command will remove all previously migrated files in the `build folder` and add new migrated files of smart contracts.

Comment: For me changing the initial migration to `.export` broke it too not just my deploy...so both files I have use `module.exports` but I used `truffle migrate --reset` and for some reason my second deploy file also worked, while the first time it didn't...